# External javascript- not doing well

Tags: javascript, jsp, validation

I am having an issue while using external java script. I am making some mistake due to which form validation is not doing well. It is doing well when java script code is internal. When I place it in external file it is doing nothing.Sometimes it work. Sometimes not.I am using net beans IDE. Here is the code.

> html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js" ></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.jpg">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
     <div class="header"></div>
     <img src="dms_logo.gif" style="align:center;">
     <div class="continer">

         <div class="myForm1" style="height:200px; width:300px; float:left;">
            <h2>MTC</h2>
            <form name="myForm1" action="access.jsp" method="get" onsubmit="return validateMtc()">
                <br/>MSISDN:<input type="text" name="MISDN" maxlength="11">
                <br/>RECIEPIENT:<input type="text" name="recipient" maxlength="12">
                <br/>DONOR:<input type="text" name="donor" maxlength="10">
                <br/>Date:<input type="text" name="date" value="">
                <br/>RN#:<input type="text" name="rn" value="" maxlength="5">
                <br/>Issue:<input type="text" name="Issue">
                <br/>SR:<input type="text" name="SR" maxlength="14">

                <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <br/><input type="reset" name="Reset">


            </form>

            <form name="search1" action="search_misdn.jsp" method="get">
                <br/><input type="submit" value="Search">
                <input type="text" value="Enter MSISDN" name="search">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="myform2" style="float:left; height:200px; width:300px;">
            <h2>O.C.S</h2>
            <form name="myForm2" action="ocs.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_ocs()">
                <br/><span>MSISDN:<input type="text" name="MISDN" maxlength="11"></span>
                <br/><span>SR:<input type="text" name="SR" maxlength="14"></span>
                <br/><span>REASON:<input type="text" name="reason"></span>
                <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <br/><input type="reset" name="Reset">

            </form>
            <form name="search1" action="search_misdn.jsp" method="get">
                <br/><input type="submit" value="Search">
                <input type="text" value="Enter MSISDN" name="search">
            </form>
        </div> 
        <div class="myform3" style="float:left; height:200px; width:300px;">
            <h2>K.B.C</h2>
            <form  name="myForm3" action="kbc.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="validate_kbc()">
                <br/>MSISDN:<input type="text" name="MISDN" maxlength="11">
                <br/>SR:<input type="text" name="SR" maxlength="14">
                <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <br/><input type="reset" value="Reset">

            </form>
            <form name="search1" action="search_misdn.jsp" method="get">
                <br/><input type="submit" value="Search">
                <input type="text" value="Enter MSISDN" name="search">
            </form>
        </div>

     </div>
 </div>



</body>
```

> myscript.js

```
//alert(1);
var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
var Datee=/^[0-9-]*$/ig;///^\d{1, 2}\/\d{1, 2}\/\d{4}$/;    
var alpha_Numeric=/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ig;
var alpha=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;
function validateMtc()
{

var a = document.forms["myForm1"]["MISDN"].value;
var b = document.forms["myForm1"]["Issue"].value;
var c = document.forms["myForm1"]["SR"].value; 
var d = document.forms["myForm1"]["date"].value;
var e = document.forms["myForm1"]["recipient"].value;
var f = document.forms["myForm1"]["donor"].value;
var g = document.forms["myForm1"]["rn"].value;

if(a == "" || b == "" || c == "" || d == "" || e="" || f="" || g="")
{  
    alert("Manadotry fields should not left blank");
    document.myForm1.MISDN.focus();
    document.myForm1.Issue.focus();
    document.myForm1.SR.focus();
    document.myForm1.date.focus();
    document.myForm1.recipient.focus();
    document.myForm1.donor.focus();
    document.myForm1.rn.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!a.match(numbers))
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only in MSISDN field');  
    document.myForm1.MISDN.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!b.match(alpha_Numeric))   
{  
    alert('Please input numeric and alphabets only in ISSUE field');  
    document.myForm1.Issue.focus();
    return false;
}  
else if(!c.match(numbers))  
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only SR field');  
    document.myForm1.SR.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!d.match(Datee))
{
    alert('Please input correct date in DATE field (dd-mm-yy)');  
    document.myForm1.date.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!e.match(alpha))
{
    alert('Please input aplhabets only in reciepeint filed');  
    document.myForm1.recipient.focus();
    return false;

}
else if(!f.match(alpha))
{
    alert('Please input aplhabets only in donor field');  
    document.myForm1.donor.focus();
    return false;

}
else if(!g.match(alpha_Numeric))
{
    alert('Please input aplhabets and numerics only in RN# field');  
    document.myForm1.rn.focus();
    return false;

}
else
    return true;

}
function validate_ocs()
{
var h = document.forms["myForm2"]["MISDN"].value;
var i = document.forms["myForm2"]["SR"].value;
var j = document.forms["myForm2"]["reason"].value;


if(h == "" || i == "" || j == "")
{  
    alert("Manadotry fields should not left blank");
    document.myForm2.MISDN.focus();
    document.myForm2.reason.focus();
    document.myForm2.SR.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!h.match(numbers))
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only in MSISDN field');  
    document.myForm2.MISDN.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!i.match(numbers))  
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only SR field');  
    document.myForm2.SR.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!(j.match(alpha_Numeric)))   
{  
    alert('Please input numeric and alphabets only in ISSUE field');  
    document.myForm2.Issue.focus();
    return false;
}  
else
    return true;

}
function validate_kbc()
{
var k = document.forms["myForm3"]["MSISDN"].value;
var l = document.forms["myForm3"]["SR"].value;
if(k == "" || l == "")
{  
    alert("Manadotry fields should not left blank");
    document.myForm1.MISDN.focus();
    document.myForm1.SR.focus();

    return false;
}
else if(!k.match(numbers))
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only in MSISDN field');  
    document.myForm3.MISDN.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!l.match(numbers))  
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only in SR field');  
    document.myForm3.SR.focus();
    return false;
}
else
    return true;

}
//alert('!!!');
```

Comment: It's called javascript, not java script or java scripting. Calling it either of the latter can be very confusing, especially when using java server-side.

Comment: You can not focus more than one field at a time....

Answer (score 1):

•  First of all,  You have an error on line 17.

```
if(a == "" || b == "" || c == "" || d == "" || e="" || f="" || g="")
```

e="",  should be e=="".  And the same goes for the rest of the variables.

**When you are comparing things you need to use double equals**,  (or preferrably triple).
See documentation:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

**• Further,  you should look into developer tools** which come with every major browser these days.  They have error consoles which will usually point you to the problem right away in simple situations.
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

**• And as a side note.**
JavaScript is one word.  Calling it 'java script' is confusing and wrong.

Comment: Console help me out in fixing some other errors. I have a new issue which is when i enter data I left blank myform3 fields it displays an alert box of empty fields. But clicking ok on alert box it just store empty record in DB. Why it not just stop on that page ? and not store empty record in DB

Comment: You'd have to update your code to what you currently have, I'm not really able to see what you mean.

Comment: i mean for third form when text fields are empty and submit button is clicked an alert box is displayed which prompt about missing fields which is good. But when i click ok on that alert box it disappears and current page will redirect on another page(whic is not good). It have to stay on that page after alert box disappears. Only this is happening with third form not with first two forms. I hope now you got this ?

Comment: Line 117,  you have this  var k = document.forms["myForm3"]["MSISDN"].value;   *** MSISDN should be MISDN ***  (  unless you fixed that already it will throw an error and could lead to that redirect ).

Comment: Hopefully i have helped you.  But I can't help you through the whole form. That is not the purpose of StackOverflow.  Good luck. @ABJ

Answer (score 0):

Your myscript.js file location is probably wrong.

double check that you are giving to correct location.
try and access the myscript.js file via the browser.
open the console (f12) and see if you get an error for a missing file.

Comment: It is in the same path where all files were located. Console help me out in fixing some other errors. I have a new issue which is when i enter data I left blank myform3 fields it displays an alert box of empty fields. But clicking ok on alert box it just store empty record in DB. Why it not just stop on that page ? and not store empty record in DB